# Using Parameters in LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

net. I have a doubt. How do we introduce user defined variables as parameters in where clause of a LINQ query. I am querying an XML file. Here is my code

```
    XElement books = XElement.Load(@"Friends.xml");

var titles =
   from book in books.Elements("Friend")
   where (string)book.Element("Date") == "27" && (string)book.Element("Month") == "05"
   select book.Element("Name");

foreach (var title in titles)
   Console.WriteLine(title.Value);
```

Instead of harcoding values `27` and `05`, I want to use variables instead.How to use them?

Sorry for the dumb question, I misunderstood the problem. Actually I am blocking certain dates in a calendar. Now using the

```
private void calendar1_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {....}
```

works only for non blocked dates. Since a particular day I tried with the variable was a blocked one, it wasn't working. Now please suggest me a solution for this. All I need is to click on a date(blocked or non blocked) and I have to run a event. Which event should I use??

Comment: Really? Have you even tried using a variable?

Comment: Your edit is a completelly different Question; you should make another question for that (and leaving the original here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a simply variable:

```
 XElement books = XElement.Load(@"Friends.xml");
string yourDate = "27";
string yourMonth = "05";

var titles =
   from book in books.Elements("Friend")
   where (string)book.Element("Date") == yourDate  && (string)book.Element("Month") == yourMonth
   select book.Element("Name");

foreach (var title in titles)
   Console.WriteLine(title.Value);
```

And so on. Of course, use good names that are readable according your code and system

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I think you could define a class of book with appropriate properties as XML tag. For example :

```
class Book {
  string Date {...} //
}
```

It's could be quite easy when reading XML file. Moreover, it could be nice if you build your own tree data structures executing XML file.